# Uploading Multiple Images to parse.com online database

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I am having a problem with Parse.com online database . In my app I need to upload multiple images to the Parse.com database.At this moment I am able to upload single image to parsefile and save it to parse object.Please suggest some answers.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't tried with images, but the **saveAllInBackground** worked for me. Although I'm having problems getting the objects Ids after the process complete.

Try this:

```
ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(objectsToUpload, new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if ( e == null )
                            {
                                //success

                                }
                            } else {
                                //error
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

It's worth mentioning that the **objectsToUpload** is an ArrayList of ParseObjects.
*As I said the operation worked, but I couldn't manage to get the objectsId from the objects uploaded*